# Transparent background scrollbar displays on top of content

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to achieve this:
[image]
What I already achieve:
https://plnkr.co/edit/a3XfJo6Fxtru9V5zpVYR?p=preview
[image]

```
.dropdown-menu { //container
    overflow-y: overlay;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:10px;
}
.dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar * {
    background:transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:$blue !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Does someone have any ideas how I can do that? How can I make the items stay between their container and the container's scrollbar so they looks like the design? 
I tried putting z-index in the elements but seems not to work.

Comment: I use this plugin instead. Seems like just css approach does not work. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the unit in body tag from **%** to **vw**
and you will get the over content effect.

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.7em;
  background: transparent;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c0392b;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this hack only works for the `body`. It doesn't work for any smaller things like `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `overflow:overlay` has be deprecated in all updated browser versions, use `scrollbar-gutter` instead.
[kindly check compatability here](https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow%3Aoverlay)

Answer (score 0):

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/
This plugin works pretty well. Suggested! Easy to modify as well!

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in your css file use this code

```
.dropdown-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

remember to remove `display: none;` property from your code or change it to `display: block;`

Comment: this has nothing to do with the topic