# How to make content go under scrollbar with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I know there is variety of JS libs for custom scroll but I believe with modern browsers it's better to go with native behaviour as more consistent and predictable. I assume I will have `nice` scrollbars in Chrome/Edge(Blink), `acceptable` in FF with their own simple color/sizing customisations and I won't care about other browsers.

[image]
The only problem I'm facing now is - I want `li` elements to go under the scrollbar. I tried to move content under it via `transform: translateX(15px)` / `margin-right: -15px` / `right: -15px` / `overflow: overlay` and nothing helped (**while `overflow:overlay` does the job for `<body/>` it doesn't help with inner containers**).

Any trick to achieve desired behaviour without JS?

```css
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: transparent;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: .3s;
}

*:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #c6ffdd, #fbd786, #f7797d);
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  transition: background .2s;
  display: block;
}

li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

ul:after {
  content: "Scroll ↧";
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

body {
  background: #12c2e9;
  background: #c471ed20;
  background: #444;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI this only work for body, not in any other elements, check the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697159/transparent-background-scrollbar-displays-on-top-of-content

Answer (score 3):

The `overflow: overlay` does what you want. But take in account that this feature is not a [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-4/). Also Edge will have another property `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;` [to hide scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/hide-scrollbar-in-edge-ie-1011/). Also test carefully in Firefox.

The `overflow` prop should be put on the `body` element, so scrollbar overlay on the top of `ul`.

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: overlay;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #c6ffdd, #fbd786, #f7797d);
}
```

[Working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-overlay-yzdxl) (tested in Chrome)

Comment: Please add working fiddle and make sure your answer is correct.

Comment: @AkhilAravind you right mate, this solution with `overflow: overlay` only works when set on body, while I need it on any overflowing content - `<ul/>` in my case

Comment: @Fyodor thanks but this doesn't work when set on elements other then `<body/>`

Comment: @Fyodor I edited initial code so it will be more obvious what I want to achieve

Comment: removed in chrome 114